# Where has the what's new webpart gone in sharepoint 2013? What replaces it?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365

Older versions of sharepoint had a webpart under social collaboration that could display recent activity in all document libraries within a given site. This webpart no longer exists in sharepoint 2013 (at least not online). I'm wondering if anyone knows of a method to replicate the functionality of this deprecated webpart...

Thanks in advance.

Dave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Content Search Web Part is the replacement.

First you need to activate **Cross-Site Collection Publishing** site collection feature to get any data from the Content Search Web Part. The (not so) funny thing is you can add the CSWP without activating the feature, but you won't have any data presented.

Be sure to have a subscription/license containing Cross-Site Publishing abilities, currently Enterprice E3 plan.

Comment: Just want to mention that I'm working in an O365 environment, I wasn't very clear about that in my OP. I couldn't see the CSWP as an option. I've put together a CQWP to do what I need, I'll probably revisit this later. Thanks for your answer; it seems like a good response to my situation, even if I didn't use the information. Marking as answer.

Comment: @user2808611 Thank you! It takes some practice to realize that SharePoint Online really is part of O365. When you have the time, explore the CSWP cause it's the best MS made in years. Don't hesitate to ask again!

Answer (score 3):

The Content Search web part does this. And there are some built-in queries for recent items.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Paul. From what I understand this webpart should be available OOTB under content rollup webparts, but I don't appear to have the option available to me. Is there anything I need to do to activate this feature for use?